# Exclude a class from instrumentation with EMMA via command prompt

Tags: junit, code-coverage, command-prompt, emma

I am generating code coverage reports with EMMA, covering classes in a dynamic web project.
To do that, I use the command in comand prompt *java -cp emma.jar emma instr -m overwrite -ip"....\workspace\p3"*

That instruments the class I do want to instrument and the Junit test class, I want to exclude the test class from instrumentation and coverage..in EMMA help it states the parameter *-ix , -filter* to do inclusion and exclusion but I can't seem get the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

-ix -com.....

- for exclusion and + for inclusion.

example

-ix +com.foo.*,-com.foo.test.*,-com.foo.*Test*

If this didn;t work please try the classes within single quotes

-ix '-com.foo.*'